# Why does the Torah mention that Lot went with Avram twice?

Tags: abraham, parashat-lech-lecha

Why does the Torah in Parshas Lech Lecha feel the need to say "vayeilech ito Lot", and Lot went with him (Avram)?  The very next passuk tells us how Avram took Sarai his wife, Lot his nephew, and so on with him when he left Charan. (See [Bereishis 12:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm#1)-4.)

Answer (score 4):

Most meforshim focus on the word "ito" in the first instance, and contrast it to "imo" but on 12:5, the Beit Halevi [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.5?lang=bi&with=Beit%20HaLevi%20on%20Torah&lang2=en) that there were 2 different stages -- the first was Lot's decision to go and the second was Avraham's decision to take him:

> וילך אתו לוט כו' ויקח אברהם את שרה אשתו ואת לוט בן אחיו. הא דהזכיר הכתוב שנית ללוט משום דאברהם נהג בלוט כמו שהוא הדין בגר דמי שבא להתגייר לא היו מקבלין אותו רק דוחין אותו ורק אם מתחזק שוב מקבלין אותו וכמו שנהגה נעמי בתחילה אמרה להם שובנה בנותי ואחר כך כשראתה כי מתאמצת ללכת אתה קבלה אותה. וכן כאן בתחילה לא לקחו אברהם עמו רק לוט הלך מעצמו ואחר כך ויקח אברם כו' ואת לוט:

Comment: I guess the question is, why did Lot decide to go? Also, if Lot had already decided to go with Avram, why would Avram need to decide to take him? Maybe it's that Lot _asked_ Avram if he could go with him, and Avram concurred, hence the words "Vayikach Avram...Es Lot"?

Comment: According to this opinion, Avraham was dealing with Lot like a convert and was rejecting him initially. Jot makes his own decision to go anyway, and THEN Avraham agrees to take him.

Answer (score 2):

[R. Joseph Ibn Kaspi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Caspi) has a comment that might be coming to address this, but he doesn't really explain himself. He just notes that the Torah first says that Lot went with Abraham, and then in the next verse it says that Abraham took Lot, and both are true:

> וילך אתו לוט. ואחר כך כתוב ויקח אברם וגו' ואת לוט וגו' והכל אמת ונכון

[R. David Zvi Hoffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Zvi_Hoffmann) writes that the first verse is telling us the general picture, while the second verse provides the specifics:

> וילך אברם וגו'. הרי זה משפט כללי המתבאר במפורט בפסוק הבא

However, this doesn't really explain why Lot needed to be included in the general picture.

[R. Ephraim Luntschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Ephraim_Luntschitz) gives an explanation which could, perhaps, account for the repetition. He explains that Abraham had separated from Sarah once he realized she was barren because any sexual activity with her would not result in children. That is why in 11:31 the verse describes Terach taking Lot in between taking Abraham and Sarah, i.e. Lot came between Abraham and Sarah because they had separated. However, in 12:2 God promised Abraham children, so he took Sarah back. Thus, 12:4 tells us that Lot came on his own, whereas 12:5 describes that Abraham took Sarah and Lot, i.e. he took back Sarah between him and Lot once he knew he would have kids:

> ויקח אברם את שרי אשתו ואת לוט בן אחיו. ולמעלה נאמר ויקח תרח את אברם
>   בנו ואת לוט בן הרן בן בנו ואת שרי כלתו לפי שקודם שהובטח אברם שיהיו לו
>   בנים היה מתרחק מן שרה מצד היותה עקרה לפי שכל אותן הבעילות אינן לקיום
>   המין ע"כ נאמר ותהי שרי עקרה אין לה ולד  וסמוך ליה ויקח תרח את אברם
>   וגו' לפי שהיתה עקרה על כן הכניס את לוט ביניהם  אבל אחר שנאמר ואעשך
>   לגוי גדול והובטח בבנים כתיב ויקח אברם את שרי אשתו ואת לוט  כי בלשון
>   ויקח הורה שאומר כאילו עשה לקוחין שניים תחת אשר היה פרוש ממנה כדרך
>   שנאמר וילך איש מבית לוי ויקח את בת לוי ומה שנאמר וילך אברם כאשר דבר
>   אליו ה' וילך אתו לוט  היינו לוט מעצמו הלך אחריו אבל אברם לא קרבו
>   ואדרבא הרחיקו ויקח את שרי וגו

Comment: I'm going to upvote this answer, but honestly I think this is more of a long comment.

Comment: Again, lots of [good] content but where's the answer?

Comment: @AlBerko *Thus, 12:4 tells us that Lot came on his own, whereas 12:5 describes that Abraham took Sarah and Lot, i.e. he took back Sarah between him and Lot once he knew he would have kids:*